# Fonts are loaded from the wrong path in Storybook

Tags: vue.js, vite, storybook, quasar-framework

Unfortunately, I have the problem that when I call up a page in which Quasar is integrated, the fonts are not loaded. Specifically, it looks like this in the Developer Tools (example):

```
http://localhost:6006/undefined/node_modules/@quasar/extras/roboto-font/web-font/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxM.woff
```

If I look at the CSS file that is delivered, it looks like this:

```js
import {createHotContext as __vite__createHotContext} from "/@vite/client";
import.meta.hot = __vite__createHotContext("/node_modules/@quasar/extras/roboto-font/roboto-font.css");
import {updateStyle as __vite__updateStyle, removeStyle as __vite__removeStyle} from "/@vite/client"
const __vite__id = "/var/www/html/node_modules/@quasar/extras/roboto-font/roboto-font.css"
const __vite__css = "@font-face {\n  font-family: 'Roboto';\n  font-style: normal;\n  font-weight: 100;\n  src: url(undefined/node_modules/@quasar/extras/roboto-font/web-font/KFOkCnqEu92Fr1MmgVxIIzQ.woff) format('woff');\n}\n@font-face {\n  font-family: 'Roboto';\n  font-style: normal;\n  font-weight: 300;\n  src: url(undefined/node_modules/@quasar/extras/roboto-font/web-font/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fBBc-.woff) format('woff');\n}\n@font-face {\n  font-family: 'Roboto';\n  font-style: normal;\n  font-weight: 400;\n  src: url(undefined/node_modules/@quasar/extras/roboto-font/web-font/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxM.woff) format('woff');\n}\n@font-face {\n  font-family: 'Roboto';\n  font-style: normal;\n  font-weight: 500;\n  src: url(undefined/node_modules/@quasar/extras/roboto-font/web-font/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fBBc-.woff) format('woff');\n}\n@font-face {\n  font-family: 'Roboto';\n  font-style: normal;\n  font-weight: 700;\n  src: url(undefined/node_modules/@quasar/extras/roboto-font/web-font/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmWUlfBBc-.woff) format('woff');\n}\n@font-face {\n  font-family: 'Roboto';\n  font-style: normal;\n  font-weight: 900;\n  src: url(undefined/node_modules/@quasar/extras/roboto-font/web-font/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmYUtfBBc-.woff) format('woff');\n}\n"
__vite__updateStyle(__vite__id, __vite__css)
import.meta.hot.accept()
export default __vite__css
import.meta.hot.prune(()=>__vite__removeStyle(__vite__id))
```

Here you can already see that somehow the path is not resolved correctly, here it is written `undefined`.

My `./.storybook/main.js`:

```js
/** @type { import('@storybook/vue3-vite').StorybookConfig } */
const config = {
  stories: [
    "../**/*.mdx",
    "../**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|mjs|ts|tsx)",
  ],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions",
  ],
  framework: {
    name: "@storybook/vue3-vite",
    options: {},
  },
  staticDirs: ['../node_modules'],
  docs: {
    autodocs: false,
  }
};
export default config;
```

My `./.storybook/preview.js`:

```js
import { setup } from '@storybook/vue3';
import { Quasar } from 'quasar';

// Import icon libraries
import '@quasar/extras/roboto-font/roboto-font.css'
import '@quasar/extras/material-icons/material-icons.css'
import '@quasar/extras/material-symbols-outlined/material-symbols-outlined.css'
import '@quasar/extras/fontawesome-v6/fontawesome-v6.css'
import '@quasar/extras/line-awesome/line-awesome.css'

// Import Quasar css
import 'quasar/src/css/index.sass'

import '../resources/css/app.css'

/** @type { import('@storybook/vue3').Preview } */
const preview = {
  parameters: {
    actions: { argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*" },
    controls: {
      matchers: {
        color: /(background|color)$/i,
        date: /Date$/i,
      },
    },
  },
};

export default preview;

setup((app) => {
    app.use(Quasar, {config: {}, directives: {}})
    app.config.globalProperties.$storybook = true;
});
```

My `./package.json`:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "storybook": "storybook dev -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "storybook build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@inertiajs/vue3": "^1.0.0",
    "@quasar/vite-plugin": "^1.3.0",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.5.0",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^7.5.0",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.5.0",
    "@storybook/blocks": "^7.5.0",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.2.2",
    "@storybook/vue3": "^7.5.0",
    "@storybook/vue3-vite": "^7.5.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.12",
    "axios": "^1.1.2",
    "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.7.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "postcss": "^8.4.18",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "sass": "^1.32.12",
    "storybook": "^7.5.0",
    "vite": "^4.0.0",
    "vue": "^3.2.41"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@quasar/extras": "^1.16.7",
    "quasar": "^2.13.0",
    "vue-i18n": "^9.2.2"
  }
}
```

When I then look into the source code of the `@quasar/extras/roboto-font/roboto-font.css` CSS file, I see this:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  src: url(./web-font/KFOkCnqEu92Fr1MmgVxIIzQ.woff) format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: url(./web-font/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fBBc-.woff) format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(./web-font/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxM.woff) format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: url(./web-font/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fBBc-.woff) format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: url(./web-font/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmWUlfBBc-.woff) format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  src: url(./web-font/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmYUtfBBc-.woff) format('woff');
}
```

Apparently it does not translate the `./` path correctly, which leads to the error. How can I make the translation work correctly?

If I display the same template with `npm run dev`, the fonts are integrated correctly. The problem only exists with `npm run storybook`.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug related to laravel-vite. Here is a solution described: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/22550#issuecomment-1721197301

Comment: Perhaps you can copy that answer from github here to stackoverflow, just to prevent link hopping